# store mysql query information chef

Tags: mysql, database, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to query my mysql database. I am using the `database` cookbook and can setup a connection with my database. I trying to query my database for information so now the question is how do I store than information so I can access it in another resource. Where do the results of the query get stored? This is my recipe:

```
mysql_database "Get admin users" do
    connection mysql_connection_info
    sql "Select * from #{table_name}"
    action :query
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which resource you want to use with your queried data?

Comment: @datelligent i wanted to update the `etc/group` file with the information returned from the query so it will be used in a `file` resource

Comment: Then you should use [PHP file_put_contents] (http://php.net/file_put_contents) to append data to your file.  Also can use **fwrite**. In general there are tools to create and write files or to open and update, and then store your data.

Comment: @datelligent I ended up using ruby to deal with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have experience with Ruby, this might be really confusing. There's no way to "return" the result of a provider from a Chef resource. The `mysql_database` is a `Chef::Recipe` DSL method that gets translated to `Chef::Provider::Database::Mysql` at runtime. This provider is [defined in the cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database/blob/master/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb).

If you take some time to dive into that provider, you'll can see how it executes queries, using the [`db` object](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database/blob/master/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb#L81-L94). In order to get the **results** of a query, you'll need to create your own connection object in the recipe and execute a command against it. For example

```
require 'mysql'
db = ::Mysql.new('host', 'username', 'password', nil, 'port', 'socket') # varies with setup

users = db.query('SELECT * FROM users')

#
# You might need to manipulate the result into a more manageable data 
# structure by splitting on a carriage return, etc...
#
# Assume the new object is an Array where each entry is a username.
#

file '/etc/group' do
  contents users.join("\n")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I find using good old Chef::Mixin:ShellOut / shell_out() fairly sufficient for this job and it's DB agnostic (assuming you know your SQL :) ). It works particularly well if all you are querying is one value; for multiple rows/columns you will need to parse the SQL query results. You need to hide row counts, column headers, eat preceding white-space, etc. from your result set to just get the query results you want. For example, below works on SQL Server :

Single item

```
so = shell_out!("sqlcmd ... -Q \"set nocount on; select file_name(1)\" -h-1 -W")
db_logical_name = so.stdout.chop
```

Multiple rows/columns (0-based position of a value within a row tells you what this column is)

```
so = shell_out!("sqlcmd ... -Q \"set nocount on; select * from my_table\" -h-1 -W")
rows_column_data = so.stdout.chop
# columns within rows are space separated, so can be easily parsed
```